# Spring Boot Test - Error creating bean with name SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit

I'm trying to run this project **test** class (SurveyControllerIT) and I'm getting this error below. I already tried a few things without success.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.rest.SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'spring.data.rest-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.rest.RepositoryRestProperties': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/ValidationException; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'spring.data.rest-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.rest.RepositoryRestProperties': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/ValidationException

Source code: [source](https://github.com/in28minutes/spring-boot-master-class/blob/master/05.Spring-Boot-Advanced/Step21.zip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a dependency. Try to add this to your pom (if you are using maven):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

You might have to supply a version as well, but I think it might be inherited from the Spring Boot parent.